# Prism RequestNavigate not working in a Popup window

Tags: wpf, navigation, prism, interaction, regions

I am implementing Prism navigation in a Pop up window raised with InteractionRequest object. My Main View contains a TabControl region with 2 views (view A, view b). The Main View looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="PrivateVehiclePopupRegion">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>          
</Grid>
```

View A contains a button with a command to Navigate to view B. And in the same way, view B contains a button to navigate to View A. 
All three views share the same view-model (which I made sure only one instance of the view-model was created).

View A and view B are registered in the Initialize method of the Module:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    ...
    RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.PrivateVehiclePopupRegion, typeof(PrivateVehiclePopupReadView)); // View A
    RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.PrivateVehiclePopupRegion, typeof(PrivateVehiclePopupEditView));  // View B    
}
```

When I execute the program, view A is loaded, but when the corresponding button is pressed to navigate to the other view, the NavigateToViewB() method is reached successfully, but when the RequestNavigate is called, nothing happens. I also tried to invert the order in which views are registered, so View B is registered first, and the View B is loaded, but the RequestNavigate to A doesn't work.

I added a callback method to investigate the issue, like this:

```
private void NavigateToEdit()
{
    this.regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.PrivateVehiclePopupRegion, EditUri,
        (NavigationResult nr) =>
        {
            var error = nr.Error;
            var result = nr.Result;
            // put a breakpoint here and checkout what NavigationResult contains
        });
}
```

Howerver, Error is null and Result is false... which tells nothing. Any ideas? I've done navigation before and it works fine, but this is the first time I implement navigation on a Popup window.

Comment: Make sure that you are using the same instance of the RegionManager to register the view and navigate to it. Then you should be able to navigate to the view using regionManager.RequestNavigate("PrivateVehiclePopupRegion", new Uri(typeof(PrivateVehiclePopupEditView).Name, UriKind.Relative), result =>{ });

Comment: Good point @mm8 How can I check if I am using the same instance of the RegionManager? This is a Prism object and I do not construct it... (I think)

Comment: Inject an IRegionManager in your Module class and in your view models. There is a sample app available on GitHub: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/View-Switching%20Navigation_Desktop_Unity/ViewSwitchingNavigation

Comment: You have to manually set the region manager if your view is not "inside" the visual tree so that the region manager can find the region when navigating...

Comment: Thanks @Haukinger . That was it !!! :D

Comment: This seems overly complicated. Why not just disable/enable the form inputs if you are just going to go from a read-only to edit, or back, in the same popup? Navigation for something this simple seems like overkill.

Comment: Always a pleasure... perhaps you up-vote the useful answer on the other question ;-)